# Rails minitest, database cleaner how to turn use_transactional_fixtures = false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, database-cleaner

i would like to disable use_transactional_fixtures = false in ministest to catch after_commit callback. What and where should i set-up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options. One is to create a test without transactional fixtures and hope that the changes you make to the test database isn't going to break any other tests.

```
class SomethingTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  def test_something_with_after_commit
    # do work here, which will change your test database
  end
end
```

Another option you have is to keep the transactional fixtures, but invoke the after_commit callback manually.

```
class SomethingTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def test_something_with_after_commit
    something = Something.new
    something.save
    something.after_commit
    # verify things happened as expected
  end
end
```

And yet another option is to move the logic out of the `after_commit` callback into a new object, where you can write proper tests for it without relying on the callbacks to be invoked.