# MiniTest, Capybara, Fixture, Database_Cleaner not passing at second time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, database-cleaner

The following test passed first time (after `rake db:test:prepare`) but <strike>failed</strike> gave error on subsequent run.

> Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find css "#sale_payment_btn"

```
require "test_helper"

DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction

class SaleFeatureTest < Capybara::Rails::TestCase
  include Warden::Test::Helpers
  Warden.test_mode!

  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  setup do
    login_as users(:admin), scope: :user
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium #:webkit
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  teardown do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
    Warden.test_reset!
  end

  test "Sale" do        
    visit(new_sale_path) # create new sale and redirect to it
    assert page.has_css?('#sale_payment_btn') # gave error at second time
    find(:css, '#sale_payment_btn').click # this create payment
  end
```

As I used selenium with chrome, I could see the ID of the sale. I noticed that the ID was the same for subsequent test. i.e. `980190963`

My theory is that

1. `database_cleaner` not functioning as expected. (Although I see DB cleaning sql commands on `test.log` file, I saw data remained in database)
2. `visit` does not create new `@sale` (as stated [here](http://blog.pardner.com/2013/01/rspec-gotcha-instance-variables-are-not-cleared-between-gets/) though I use minitest) because `#sal_payment_btn` is not rendered (sale already has `payment` on first run).

I'm pulling my hair around for half day now. I have tried

- `webkit` driver
- different cleaning strategy `truncation`, `deletion`

and I still can't pass the test on second run. It is running okay on manual test.

What and where did I do wrong?

P.S. I'm using the following gems

```
minitest-rails-capybara
selenium-webdriver
chromedriver-helper
database_cleaner
minitest-around
pg
```

I have read the following

- http://blog.berylliumwork.com/2013/07/rails-4-devise-3-minitest-and-capybara.html
- [Database Cleaner not working in minitest rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675125/database-cleaner-not-working-in-minitest-rails)
- [Rails minitest, database cleaner how to turn use_transactional_fixtures = false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488758/rails-minitest-database-cleaner-how-to-turn-use-transactional-fixtures-false)

Comment: I believe `rake db:test:prepare` only creates the test database and it does not run the tests. Can you post the errors that you are getting?

Comment: Yes, I am aware it does not run the tests and it __does clean the database__. After reading your comment, I think my setup of `database_cleaner` with `minitest` isn't correct and it is not cleaning the database. What is your opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've confirmed that the problem was my setup of `database_cleaner`.

#### Short version

`:transaction` strategy was not working for my setup `cucumber`+`webkit`/`selenium`. Changed to `:deletion` strategy.

#### What I learnt

It seemed I didn't study enough. I found out the following during my search for answer.

1. Someone asked [Why is the database cleaner transaction strategy not working with Cucumber and Selenium?](http://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-database-cleaner-transaction-strategy-not-working-with-Cucumber-and-Selenium) - no answer
2. [How to set up database_cleaner for Rails with Cucumber and RSpec](http://makandracards.com/makandra/30457-how-to-set-up-database_cleaner-for-rails-with-cucumber-and-rspec) stated that

   > The `:transaction` strategy does not work with Selenium
3. [`database_cleaner` readme](http://github.com) stated that `:transaction` strategy imposes bit more working

   > However, if you wind up needing to use multiple database connections in your tests (i.e. your tests run in a different process than your application) then using this strategy becomes a bit more difficult

#### Other worthy reading

- [Why you should be using Database Cleaner's `deletion` strategy](http://sevenseacat.net/2015/02/01/use_database_cleaners_deletion_strategy.html)
- most recommended way to set up `database_cleaner` with `rails`, `rspec`, `capybara` and `selenium` - http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/
- [Rails 4, Devise 3, MiniTest and Capybara for user login](http://blog.berylliumwork.com/2013/07/rails-4-devise-3-minitest-and-capybara.html)