# ActiveRecord data loss when unit testing Rails + Node.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, unit-testing, activerecord, rake

**Background:** I am unit testing a game server which is built upon rails 4.1.1 and separate socket.io/node.js for socket messaging. Messages from node.js to rails are going through RESTful http requests.
Single test case runs as follows:

```
(1) rake unit test --> (2) rails controller --> (3) node.js/socket.io --> (4) rails controller
```

**Problem description:** Some DB entries are created with ActiveRecord at **step (2)**, then upon receiving a socket message at **step (3)** node.js sends HTTP request back to rails controller and finally(!!) at **step (4)** rails controller tries to access DB entries from **step (2)**, but TEST DB contents are empty at this point.

**Question:** It seems like desired behavior of rake to cleanup TEST DB, but how can I persist TEST db across test cases and prevent such problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, I figured out the solution.

By default, rake is wrapping all tests in separate DB transactions and rolls back on cleanup. Moreover, whatever requests/queries are coming outside of TestCase are not included in transaction and not visible inside the test case.

To avoid such behavior, we have to disable transactional fixtures in **test/test_helper.rb**

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false
end
```

As downside, we have to cleanup test db manually. So @Alexander Shlenchack points out to avoid such practice in the first place and use http/socket mocks in future.

- Here is brief summary http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/
- And related question [Rails minitest, database cleaner how to turn use_transactional_fixtures = false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488758/rails-minitest-database-cleaner-how-to-turn-use-transactional-fixtures-false)

Answer (score 1):

You should prepare and send request to node app inside a test and assert response there.

But it's not a good practice. The better solution would be HTTP mocks (like **webmock** gem). This approach will save lots of time in the future.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I am sending request to node app inside rake test, as you mention. But I cannot send reply from node app to mocked http, so it goes back to a running rails server. I think data is lost at this point

Comment: You don't need to use a node app when using mocks. Please, see a good article about it: http://asquera.de/blog/2015-03-30/testing-external-apis-in-ruby/